# Comment box (social addon) starts minimized after max shown responses

Tags: comments, facebook-social-plugins

When I get 10+ comments (the number I set for visible comments) the comment entry box starts minimized, now it's easy enough to click on the button to expand it, but I would PREFER it to start open, I mean, the whole point is we want more comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the `num_posts` parameter as listed in the documentation for the Comments box:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

If that doesn't work you should file a bug in the Facebook [Bug Tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs)

Comment: Well, it is num_posts=10
However, the problem is at reaching the 10, the comment text entry defaults to minimized... and I don't want it to.